# Getting no result from table , while fetching data using laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, vuejs2

I am trying to execute simple CRUD operation using laravel. but it gives an error code 500 , when I try to fetch data from table either by laravel framework as well as with plain PHP.

Here is my controller class.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\BookModel;
use \DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function getItems()
    {
        $data = DB::select('select * from book');
        $data = BookModel::all();
        echo($data);
        return compact('data');
    }
}
```

axiom , which is been used. --->   "https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"

Model Class:

```
    <?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class BookModel extends Model {
    protected $table = "book";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

It is returning no result from the table.

Comment: Check the web server log for errors.

Comment: nothing is being printed in webserver log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) Scroll a bit down to "HTTP Error 500 - Internal server error"

Comment: @digijay no , not helpful

Comment: @JasonK attaching server log.

Comment: Does `http://localhost/lara-vue-login/public/main/getAllBooks` throw errors? What's in your laravel.log?

Comment: @kerbholz ,yes, but code is executing fine before I execute DB query , if I comment lines used for DB connectivity it works fine

Comment: What you posted is not the server log. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53843354/4178487) to see how to check the log.

Comment: It's same what i have posted. D:\Softwares\Xampp\apache\logs\error.logs

Comment: Laravel has its own logs for 500 errors. `storage/logs/laravel.log`. You should be able to see the error there. That being said, you're using `mysqli`, which goes against the point of using Laravel... You shouldn't have to use native PHP logic when you have Models and the Query Builder available.

Comment: @TimLewis I am using laravel model , then getting no result in return. I have updated the code with model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I changed my controller to

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\BookModel;
use \DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function getItems()
    {
        $data = BookModel::all();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

But it was giving null result when I was doing something like below

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\BookModel;
use \DB;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function getItems()
    {
        $data = BookModel::all();
        return view('admin')->withTasks($data);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it was not working earlier?

Anyways , Thanks everyone for your help.

Cheeeeeeeeerrsssss!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `response()` to return data without **view**. 
Like below the code returns the JSON data from your `BookModel` that sometimes we need through the ajax request like `axios`.

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function getItems()
    {
        $data = BookModel::all();
        return response()->toJson($data);
    }
}
```

With view you can do the following:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    function getItems()
    {
        $data = BookModel::all();
        return view('admin', compact('data'));
    }
}
```

Where you can access the `BookModel` data through `$data` variable in your `admin.blade.php`